# Images display on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I am trying to display images in UITableViewCell, I'm using web service to get the image names. Here is what i'm getting in the response of web service.

```
"2514466130834f61a9g38d57h0e2cb-25-ProfilePic.PNG",
"26144482598634297156heb8c0dafg-26-ProfilePic.PNG",
"2714464392629h60253gd4ec8b1f7a-27-ProfilePic.PNG",
"2814449113316a7gh5db0e2139c84f-28-ProfilePic.PNG",
"2914454043856e3519ah0dbf27cg84-29-ProfilePic.PNG"
```

The above response is saved in the array format. These array objects are then append on a url, And I need to display images on `UIImageView`. 
Please Help me.

Comment: You have a web service that returns a list of image file names?  And you want to download those images and display them in a table?  There's a lot of pieces to this task.  Which have you already accomplished, and which do you have trouble with?

Comment: Are you using custom cell of default one ? and please share code, so I can help you in better way...

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your url like below.

```
// Consider this is your prefix url 
NSString *urlPrefix = @"https://your_url_prefix/"; // like http://stackoverflow.com/

// Consider this is the array you parsed from the web service
NSArray *resourceArray = @[@"2514466130834f61a9g38d57h0e2cb-25-ProfilePic.PNG", @"26144482598634297156heb8c0dafg-26-ProfilePic.PNG", @"2714464392629h60253gd4ec8b1f7a-27-ProfilePic.PNG", @"2814449113316a7gh5db0e2139c84f-28-ProfilePic.PNG", @"2914454043856e3519ah0dbf27cg84-29-ProfilePic.PNG"];
```

Prepare the resource url in your tableView's data source method: `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSString *resourceURL = [urlPrefix stringByAppendingString:[resourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

and use `SDWebImage` library to load the image and set that in to your cell `imageView` like

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:resourceURL];
```

Note: `SDWebImage` lib can be downloaded from [SDWebImage Git](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
Add this library files in your project and import like below to use.

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

First download Asynchronous Class [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8onwz550lfwcc3y/ASYNC_IMAGE.zip?dl=0)

Then put your .m file

> #import "AsyncImageView.h"

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpletableidentifier=@"simpletableidentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpletableidentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc ]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpletableidentifier];
    } 

   AsyncImageView *Galleryimg = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)];
   Galleryimg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
   Galleryimg.clipsToBounds=YES;
   Galleryimg.tag=i;
   Galleryimg.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[Yourstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [scroll addSubview:Galleryimg];
   return cell;
}
```